# Fetch Objects from CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, count, nsfetchrequest

I have a Problem with my CoreData Attribute "picturecount" (Int) so i have a UICollectionView in there are Images and i save the Imagecount in CoreData so far so good, when i print it in the PhtoController it runs and shows the topical picturecount. So in the EverydayController i would give it to a Label names: "CountPic" but picturecount is alway 0 what can be the problem ? 
Thanks for your Help.

PhotoController: UICollectionViewController

```
  let CountPicture = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Everyday", inManagedObjectContext: self.mgdContext) as! Everyday
    CountPicture.picturecount = everypicture.count
    print("\(CountPicture.picturecount)coreinfo")
    do {try self.mgdContext.save()} catch {print("Error")}
```

EverydayController:

```
var everyday = [Everyday] ()


var mgdContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext


func loaddata () {
    let fetchrequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Everyday")
    everyday = try! mgdContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchrequest) as! [Everyday]}

delegateLoangeController!.CountPic.title = "\(everyday[0].picturecount!) Picture"
```

Comment: Can you ensure the CountPic is properly connected to the outlet?

Comment: Yes it is because the String "Picture" is shown. The picturercount shows 0 in the Label \(everyday[0].picturecount!) .